# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in [...]/domain_conf.module on line 37

Tags: multi-sites, domain-access

I can't figure out what is causing the problem and how to fix it. The error from domain_conf.module is in this foreach:

```
$data = array();
$data = db_fetch_array(db_query("SELECT settings FROM {domain_conf} WHERE domain_id = %d", $domain['domain_id']));
if (!empty($data)) {
    global $conf;
    $settings = domain_unserialize($data['settings']);

    // Overwrite the $conf variables.
    foreach ($settings as $key => $value) {
      if ($value === 'domain-conf-ignore') {
        continue;
      }
    ...
```

I did `var_dump($settings)` before the `foreach` and the output was `bool(false)`.

---

### Background:

This is a copy of our live site on a new local webserver we set up for development and testing. So I don't know if this has always existed and is only showing up now that Xdebug is on or if this is new due to the migration.

I installed **variable check** module and there are no problems with my **variable** table.

### Update:

I did a couple more `var_dump`s and found that it is domain_id "11" and found that in the `domain_conf` table. I opened the blob and found a couple of serialized string that I can fix.

Now I just need to find out how to edit the blob and hopefully the issue will be  fixed.

Comment: Just re-save your settings. If that doesn't work, then this will break next time you change settings anyway. In that case, report it as a bug to the module maintainer.

Comment: I'm trying that but nothing has changed. I'm thinking maybe it was a problem that always existed but I am only seeing it now that Xdebug is on.

Comment: Sounds like a module bug to me.